# how to stack dojo request if data from two URLs needed

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

How can I stack the dojo request function in case I need data from two sources to continue?

The following does not work and would probably start loading file2.json only after file1.json, although there is no dependency at this point:

```
require(["dojo/request"], function(request){
   request("file1.json", {handleAs: "json"}).then(function(datajson1){
      request("file2.json", {handleAs: "json"}).then(function(datajson2){

            use datajson1 and datajson2 here
```

Comment: I think [dojo/promise/all](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/promise/all.html#dojo-promise-all) fits your requirement.

Comment: thank you Frank, this was exactly what I needed. 
btw: the stacked dojo request functions above did also work then, one of them just returned invalid json before.
I now use dojo promise to load both files asynchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your requests will return to you a Promise. The `dojo/promise/all` module do exactly what you need: wait for the two Promises to resolve and then you can do whatever you need with the responses. For more information about the `all` module, here's the [link](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/promise/all.html#dojo-promise-all).

In you case, the code should be something like:

```
require(["dojo/promise/all", "dojo/request"], function(all, request) {
    var promiseA = request("file1.json", {handleAs: "json"}),
        promiseB = request("file2.json", {handleAs: "json"});

    all([promiseA, promiseB).then(function(results) {
        // Results is the array with the promises results.
        // results[0] will be the return from promiseA
        // results[1] will be the return from promiseB
    });
}
```